# promise chain is repeating itself after the call takes too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, angular-http

I have a very long promise chain inside of a $http.get call that takes quite a few minutes to complete. The part that takes a long time is a for loop that iterates through 160 some array elements and runs a long series of socket connect tests. However around the 84th iteration in the for loop, the whole promise chain (or maybe the get call) starts all over again. While the other one is still running. Then once the first one finishes the res.send never goes through while the new chain runs and this repeats ad infinitum.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 fs.readdir('C:\\Temp\\hostPorts', function(err, files) {
  console.log('files', files);
  chooseFile(files).then(response => {readTheFile(response).then(async (result) => {
    splitText(result).then( async (final) => {
      console.log('final version', final);
      res.send({file: final});
    })
    // res.send({file: result});
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    }) //end catch
  }); //end promise
 }); //end read
}); //end get
```

this is my get call, the splitText function is where it is getting stuck. I will post the source for the splitText function below but I'm certain that its somehow creating two instances since every time at the 84th iteration my terminal console reprints the initial console.log('files', files) and then runs through the other promises in the chain.

It is eventually finishing the first one because the console.log('final version', final) does print out. but the res.send never happens and the second promise chain continues to run. then the third, etc, etc.

here's the code from the long loop

```
async function splitText(file){
  let tableData = "<table  border=1 cellspacing=0><tr>";

  let splited = file.trim().split(/\s+/);
        //vars for checking connectivity

        for (let i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
            console.log(splited[i] + " " + i);
            if(i < 4 ) {
                tableData += "<th>" + splited[i] + "</th>";
                //if its less than 4 print out table headers
            }
            else if (i == 4){
                tableData += "</tr><tr><td>" + splited[i] + "</td>";
                //if its 4 create a new row for data
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0){
                //if modulo 3 is 0 then its on a port, checks connectivity and adds it to the row as data after port
                //then starts a new row
                let host = splited[(i - 1)]; //1 index ago was host
                let port = parseInt(splited[(i)]); //current array index is port
                console.log('host: ' + host );
                console.log('port: ' + port );
                await testPort(port, host).then(async (reachable) => {
                  console.log(reachable);
                  if (reachable) {
                    tableData += "<td>" + splited[i] + "</td><td>" + "<font color=\"GREEN\">UP</font>" + "</tr><tr>";
                   }
                  else {
              tableData += "<td>" + splited[i] + "</td><td>" + "<font color=\"RED\">DOWN</font>" + "</tr><tr>";
                    }
                });
              } //end else if
           else {
                tableData += "<td>" + splited[i] + "</td>";
                //otherwise adds tabledata
             }
        } //end for
     return tableData;
} //end function
```

And this is the async function that checks if the host/ports are up.

```
async function testPort(port, host){
 return new Promise(resolve => {
    const socket = new net.Socket();

      const onError = () => {
        socket.destroy();
        resolve(false);
      };

      socket.setTimeout(10000);
      socket.on('error', onError);
      socket.on('timeout', onError);

      socket.connect(port, host, () => {
        socket.end();
     resolve(true);
   }); //end promise
 });
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue of the HTTP. get restarting after it takes too long however i have the timeout set to 5 minutes. Or if this is the promise chain restarting after not getting a response. But I'm really banging my head on this one as either way im never getting data back to my client and as far as I see i never recalled a function or created an infinite loop.

Comment: Add more logs to find out what exactly is repeating.

Comment: You really should learn how Promises work, and what the meaning of `await` and `async` is. You don't have proper chaining of the Promises in your route so you are not able to log any error that happens in those Promises, and the `asnyc`  there is useless.

Comment: Can you put a sample of your hostports file (at least like 10-15 columns space separater)? It was not clear how "i == 4" column (first column in first data row) handled for 2nd column onwards...

Comment: the others are handled by the modulo 3. I dont start handling them there until after the first row because running the code I have in the else modulo 3 on table headers opposed to ports/hosts would return errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what framework you are using and whether it has internal timeout for processing the request to retry. One of the problem with the above code is testing the network connection is happening serially. When you have lot of hosts to check, it bound to fail/timeout. You can test multiple hosts in parallel. For this, the code to split, test & built output should be separated. Here is a rudimentary version.

```js
function _splitText(file = '') {
  let ret = {
    header: [],
    hosts: {}
  };
  if (!file.length) {
    return ret;
  }
  //split the content
  let splitted = file.trim().split(/\s+/);
  if (splitted.length % 3 !== 1 && splitted.length < 4) {
    console.log('Invalid data!');
    return ret;
  }

  //get header
  ret.header = splitted.splice(0, 4);
  while (splitted.length) {
    const [name, host, port, ...rest] = splitted;
    ret.hosts[name] = {
      host,
      port,
      isReachable: false
    };
    splitted = rest;
  }
  return ret;
}
async function testPort(name, port, host) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const socket = new net.Socket();

    const onError = () => {
      socket.destroy();
      resolve({
        name,
        isReachable: false
      });
    };

    socket.setTimeout(10000);
    socket.on('error', onError);
    socket.on('timeout', onError);

    socket.connect(port, host, () => {
      socket.end();
      resolve({
        name,
        isReachable: true
      });
    }); //end promise
  });
}
async function testPortsParallel(o, nParallel = 5, timeout = 10000) {
  const hostnames = Object.keys(o.hosts);
  let temp;
  while ((temp = hostnames.splice(0, nParallel))) {
    //create async promise for all hosts and wait for them at one go.
    await Promise.all(temp.map(v => testPort(v, o.hosts[v].host, o.hosts[v].port))).then(values => values.forEach(v => o.hosts[v.name].isReachable = v.isReachable));
  }
}

function buildOutput(o) {
  let ret = '<table  border=1 cellspacing=0>';
  //add header
  ret += '<tr><th>' + o.header.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';
  //add hosts
  ret += o.hosts.keys().map(v => '<tr><td>' + [v, o.hosts[v].host, o.hosts[v].port].join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>').join('');

  ret += '</table>'
}

async function splitText(s) {
  let data = _splitText(s);
  await testPortsParallel(data);
  return buildOutput(data);
}

splitText('name host port IsReachable 1 a b 2 c d');
//console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Hope this might be somewhat helpful.You can adjust the number of servers to test in parallel as per your need.

Note: There is a slight chagne in your testPort fn as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are not helping yourself by mixing three different styles on async syntax. The first step should really be to simplify the code into a single style which often reveals the issue.

At a glance I suspect your issue is how you are chaining promises. Some of your then statements are executing new promises but not returning a promise which means you create multiple promise chains. You also are losing errors as they have no catch clauses.
I would refactor into

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.readdir('C:\\Temp\\hostPorts', function(err, files) {
    sendFile()
      .then(result => res.send(result));
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendError("Boom");
      }
  }
} 

async function sendFile() {
  const file= await chooseFile(files);
  const contents = await readTheFile(file);
  const splitContents = await splitText(contents);
  return {file: splitContents};
}
```

This uses async await which is easier to read than standard promise chains.  You always have to remember to return Promises from your then clauses with classic promise chains or you can get into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I added in your changes as well as some extra console logs and I'm still getting the same issue where on the 84th iteration in the for loop the whole call restarts. Thanks to the console logs i confirmed that its the entire get call that is refiring, not the promise chain. I have no idea what could cause the same get call to be double firing

Comment: Well for starters, write a test for the function by itself. This will speed up your testing time and allow you to verify that it occurs in this place. Secondly, async functions should return values instead of modifying values via closure. You are using async await so if you are using .then inside an async function you are doing something wrong. Rewrite the async part to return values.